# Datepicker custom selection Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to make the datepicker like this:

just a brief intro, my project is to make something like employee holiday request.
so that the employee can apply their day-off request, but here's what my boss ask for the requirement. **Sunday, and world official holiday need to be automatically added when the user picked the previous date or after.**

Ex : 25 December is Christmas day.
Then I (as the employee) lets say pick 24th Dec and 26th Dec as my day-off. Then I may not skipped 25th December, it needs to be calculated as well.
That means I already used my 3 days off chance(my office only allow 12 days day-off in a year).

Sorry for the long explanation, I'm a newbie. I just want to know is this possible and if so, how? can you at least show me the trick. THANK YOU SO SO MUCH

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [ask] and [mcve] for better help.

Comment: Please see [Ask].  And as of this writing, you didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].